# Navigate through textfields in the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using custom cell in `TableView`. My Tableview has 5 rows and I am reusing the cell 5 times, the cell is having the `Textfield`. I need to navigate through the textfields in the tableview and press of next button on the keyboard. 
Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What action you actually want to do when you press next button?

Comment: I need to go to next textfield in the tableview on press of next button

Comment: give tags to each uitextfield in a cell. with next button pressed make the other textfield becomeFirstResponder

Comment: Its quite painful friend.

Comment: I know but I am using the same cell, technically it contains the same textfield, so how can I give the tag to the textfield.

Comment: If it all 5 textfield in one cell you can navigate one by one which gonna be easy  but in 5 cells it should be complex..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I think you should try [TPKeyboard](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding) for handling `UITextfields` in `UITableView`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `textFieldShouldReturn` method is used for this purpose. A sample is below. You need to modify it to use in your code.  The class in which you are going to write this method, object of that class must be set as `delegate` for those textfields

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField == <textField1>) {
        [<textField2> becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == <textField2>) {
        [<textField3> becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. In common case inside the view it is possible. But in every single cell , only you can step out from one field to another field based on the indexpath alone.

Comment: Yes, correct. Thats why I said its just a sample of the method to be used and OP has to modify it.

Comment: I need to identify the textfield by giving the tag that is equal to indexpath.row. I am writing a block inside a textfield should return method and I am calling it in main controller.

Comment: Yes, you can set that tag for your *textField*, based on which you can navigate to the *textField* in next cell. Its a bit complex but I guess this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method when you end editing textfield so check the particular textfield and navigate

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Also on returning the textfield you can navigate

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField;
```

Answer (score 0):

At first change class of your view scene to your viewcontroller in storyboard.
At first make your custom cell with identifier `cell` (in my case).
Put textfield and set tag `101` (in my case).
Inherit UITextFieldDelegate and keyboard toolbar value like this:

```
@interface TableViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField* textField1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField* textField2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField* lastTextField;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* string1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString* string2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIToolbar* keyboardToolbar;
@end
```

In `viewDidLoad` method write code below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //
    self.keyboardToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    self.keyboardToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    self.keyboardToolbar.items = @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(cancelNumberPad:)],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                 target:nil
                                                 action:nil],
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Apply" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                  target:self
                                                  action:@selector(doneWithNumberPad:)]];
    [self.keyboardToolbar sizeToFit];
}
```

And implement these methods:

```
-(void)cancelNumberPad:(id)sender {
    [self.lastTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)doneWithNumberPad:(id)sender {
    if(self.lastTextField == self.textField1) {
        [self.textField2 becomeFirstResponder];
    } else {
        [self.lastTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

And write initialize code for cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UITextField* textField = [cell viewWithTag:101];
    textField.inputAccessoryView = self.keyboardToolbar;
    textField.delegate = self;

    if(0 == indexPath.section && 0 == indexPath.row) {
        self.textField1 = textField;
    } else if(0 == indexPath.section && 1 == indexPath.row) {
        self.textField2 = textField;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

And now we have to implement UITextFieldDelegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == self.textField1) {
        self.string1 = [self.string1 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    } else if(textField == self.textField2) {
        self.string2 = [self.string2 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    self.lastTextField = textField;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self doneWithNumberPad:nil];
    return YES;
}
```